# Android 7 Nougat is not listed on the Platform Version options

Tags: appium

I'm using Appium 1.4.16.1 and I don't see Android 7 Nougat (API Level 24) listed on the Capabilities Platform Version drop down. Can anyone please tell me what do [image]I need to do ?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Appium 1.6.4 started supporting Android 7

Visit this link

https://github.com/appium/appium/releases

So you have to upgrade your appium server to 1.6.4

Comment: But there I could find only source code. Where can I get desktop app?

Comment: Appium 1.6.0 onwards doesn't support ui version. You have to install it using nodejs or can say using console.

Comment: thanks. I used "npm install -g appium" and installed.